# How do I get the parent window's grandson, or grandson's son

Tags: windows, winapi, handle, childwindow

I have a main window class, called for example *file*, and each file window, has several child windows, for example *pages*, and each *page* has several child windows, for example *text boxes*, etc, etc..
How can I get handle of the *file*, from handle of the *text box*, or one of the text box's child windows.
There is a function `GetParent()`, but it returns the parent one level up, and I am looking for such a function that returns the top level window.
I wrote my code that performs the action, as follows, but my question if there is a system function in win32?

```
HWND GetTopLevelWindow(HWND hChild)
{
    HWND topParent = 0;
    HWND h1 = hChild;
    HWND h2;

    while(topParent == 0)
    {
        h2 = GetParent(h1);
        if(h2 == 0)
            topParent = h1;
        else
            h1 = h2;
    }
    return topParent;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `GetAncestor(GA_ROOT)` or some variation?

Comment: yes, it should be an answer. `GetAncestor(hWndChild, GA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`GetAncestor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with an argument of `GA_ROOT`. For example

```
HWND topParent = GetAncestor(hChild, GA_ROOT);
```